# Declaring visits to the United Kingdom

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland, northern-ireland

I am an Indian citizen with a valid short term standard visitor visa for the UK and have used it once to travel to the UK recently. Given this scenario, I am eligible to travel to Ireland under the short stay visa waiver program without the need of any extra Irish visa.

However, I plan to make a day trip from Ireland to Northern Ireland by a tour company. I have learnt online that there may or may not be checks once I cross the border into the UK and exit from the UK while returning to Ireland. I will be having a valid visa to the UK of course and eligible to enter Ireland using the same visa on the way back as well.

My question is, how do I declare this visit of mine to the UK if I have to apply for another UK visa in the future, because there may be no one recording my entry and exit into/out of the UK? Do I need to report to the police in Belfast (I will be going here) or send any details to the Home Office or UKVI? If I happen to file another UK visa in the future, can I just honestly mention that I traveled to the Northern Ireland for a day and submit the tour tickets as proof even if no one checked or recorded my visit?

Comment: Potentially relevant (although for the other way round) -https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102916/where-to-obtain-irish-passport-stamp-when-entering-from-northern-ireland

Comment: Lots of people seem to get stressed about the fact that they don't have passport stamps for a particular trip, and therefore they will be in trouble when applying for a visa. Just to point out, there are many foreign trips that don't involve passport stamps (eg, an EU citizen won't ever get a passport stamp when traveling to another EU country). Border officers don't expect all declared trips to have a corresponding stamp. UK border officers are well aware of the existence of the Common Travel Area.

Comment: @MJeffryes For those of us lucky enough to carry powerful passports travel histories are largely irrelevant since we rarely have to contend with visa formalities. For those of us without that luxury a demonstrable travel history is a valuable commodity. I can understand why the OP is concerned about it.

Comment: @trollster You could state that you spent x days in total in the Common Travel Area https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138745/what-do-non-eu-schengen-citizens-need-to-do-when-travelling-within-the-common-tr